# How do you pronounce "Git"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

How do you pronounce [*Git*](http://git-scm.com/)?
Because I don't live in a country that uses English, I haven't heard it yet.
In my country, some people use [ɡɪt] and others use [d͡ʒɪt].
Which is the one that most people use?

Comment: The pronunciation is [ɡít]

Comment: In fact *git* (from one of its early senses of *bastard*) is cognate to *beget*. So it's not surprising (though such things aren't always necessary) that it's pronounced with the same consonants as in *get*.

Comment: I note that some of the replies have assumed that the question is about the Source management system [git](http://git-scm.com/) and others have not made this assumption. It doesn't affect the question, but those who have not heard of the system may find some of the replies rather strange.

Comment: The original question made it somewhat more clear, by capitalizing the G in "Git," but it was later edited to its present state.

Comment: @ColinFine: The version control system is also named after the colloquial (British) English word for stupid or annoying person. In the words of Linus Torvalds: "I'm an egotistical bastard, and I name all my projects after myself. First Linux, now git."

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: just because he said it, doesn't _necessarily_ make it true. That comment sounds like a self-deprecatory joke: "git" is not the first epithet that would occur to an English speaker to use on themselves (no, I know he's not English). It seems much more likely that he chose it from "git" = "get", perhaps with that joke in mind from the first.

Comment: @ColinFine: Of course it's a self-deprecatory joke. :-) Isn't that obvious? And yes, as I said, I was just pointing out that *get*, *git* and *Git* are all cognates, which does not *necessarily* mean that they are pronounced with the same consonants, but which does make it unsurprising that they are. (The quote was to show that Linus was aware of the common word, and intended the name of his vcs to be the same.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Oh, right. To demonstrate the pronunuciation that's fine. I thought you were taking his comment at face value.

Comment: IPA has no `[í]`. It’s simply `[gɪt]`.

Comment: It's (roughly) 깆.

Comment: @tchrist IPA does have [í], but it's not the sound in _git_: it's [i] in a high-level tone.

Comment: In India most people pronounce it as jit. It is git not jit. Reference : From github official video from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3jLJU7DT5E

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you need to know for sure, *go to the source*!

[Video presentation about Git by Linus Torvalds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8?t=1m30s)

This confirms that `[gɪt]` is the expected pronunciation.

Comment: wow, this is the perfect answer., I like the `go to the source!`

Comment: What in the world is an acute accent in IPA? There’s [no such diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Diacritics). Surely you just mean `[gɪt]` for the pronunciation!

Comment: Apart from the high tone diacritic.

Comment: I think the timestamp you've chosen is wrong. Should be around 1:28 : https://youtu.be/4XpnKHJAok8?t=88

Answer (score 11):

The word is pronounced [ɡɪt].  This is a homophone for the verb ***[get](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get)***, which is an intentional reference to its role in retrieving a source from a repository.

Comment: For (most?) American speakers, it isn't a homophone; /gɛt/, not /ɡít/, is a common pronunciation of *get*, as your reference shows.

Comment: Somewhat true, but check out the pronunciation note from my source:  The pronunciation  [git]  for get has existed since the 16th century. The same change is exhibited in  [kin] for can and  [yit] for yet. The pronunciation [git] is not regional and occurs in all parts of the country.

Comment: @Brendon: I would say that *git* has to be regional. In 1893, someone [describing the Mississippi accent](http://dialectblog.com/2011/10/24/mississippi-accent-in-1893/) specifically remarked that they used *git* instead of *get*, so it was certainly regional back then. The pronunciation *git* has probably diffused somewhat since, and you might be able to find speakers using it in all areas of the U.S., but my impression is that it is much more common in the South.

Comment: I can only go by what the source says.  And, for what it's worth, I live in the Northeast and my pronunciation tends toward *git*, along with most people in my county.

Comment: Where I live (middle of the USA) the only time they would be pronounced the same is when telling a stray animal (or child) to leave. In that case `get` would be pronounced with a short i sound instead of a short e. `Get` in this case is an imperative verb, roughly short for "Get yourself out of here". I've seen some people attempt to alleviate the confusion in this one instance by spelling this particular meaning of "get" as "*git*".

Comment: @T.E.D.  So do you live in [Lebanon, Kansas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_center_of_the_contiguous_United_States) or in [Belle Fourche, South Dakota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_centers_of_the_United_States)? :)

Comment: @tchrist - Close: http://onlyinoklahoma.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/journey-to-the-center-of-the-universe-in-oklahoma/ :-). That's about 300 miles SSE of the geographic center, and 250 miles SW of the population median.

Comment: Source for "intentional reference" please!

Answer (score 5):

It never occurred to me to even think of saying it with anything other than a hard G and a short I, so [ɡɪt].

Comment: Well you know, it would also never occur to most people that gif (which stands for **G**raphics **I**nterchange **F**ormat) was supposed pronounced `jif` but [that's that its creator says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Pronunciation_of_GIF). I checked some gif files into git. PS: I use a hard G on both but just saying it's certainly a valid question given other `gi?` names :P